# Way to vectorize this loop? Multiply two matrices, store information, do this many times without looping

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vectorization, apply

Suppose (small numbers in this example) I have an array that is

```
3 x 14 x 5
```

call this

```
set.seed(1)
dfarray=array(rnorm(5*3*14,0,1),dim=c(3,14,5))
```

I have a matrix that corresponds to this and is

```
39 (which is 13*3) x 14
```

Call this matrix:

```
dfmat = matrix(rnorm(13*3*14,0,1),39,14)
dfmat = cbind(dfmat,rep(1:3,13))
dfmat = dfmat[order(dfmat [,15]),]
colnames(dfmat)[15]='unit'
```

What I want to do is run this loop:

```
 costs = c(0.45, 2.11, 1.05, 1.44, 0.88, 2.30, 1.96, 1.76, 2.06, 1.54, 1.69,1.75,0)
    p = c(1,2,3,1,4,3,2,1,4,1,3,4,0)
    profit=numeric(0)
    for(i in 1:3){
            j=13
            beta = dfarray[i,,]
            Xt = dfmat [which(dfmat [,'unit']==i),1:14]    #this takes a set of 13, Xt is 13x14

            Xbeta = exp( Xt %*% beta )
            iota = c(rep(1, j))
            denom = iota%*%Xbeta
            Prob =  (Xbeta/ (iota%*%denom))
            Eprob = rowSums(Prob)/5  #the 5 coming from the last dim of array
            profit = c(profit,sum((p-costs)*Eprob))

        }


     sum(profit)
```

I cannot think of a way to vectorize the part that the loop gets around by calling

```
beta = dfarray[i,,]
Xt = dfmat [which(dfmat [,'unit']==i),]   #this takes a set of 13, Xt is 13x14
```

Comment: Would it be possible to store `dfmat` also in a 3-dim array?

Comment: Yes, it would, is there a way to do 3d array multiplication that would work?  I'm editing the code so it's reproducible right now so bear with me!

Comment: Have a look at the `tensorA` package. It provides the `mul.tensor` function. I guess you need to use the `by` argument in that function in order to loop through your index `i`.

Comment: I will look into this right now, code is reproducible now btw!

Comment: The function goes like `mul.tensor(X,i=c(),Y,j=i,by=NULL)`. `X` and `Y` would be your 3-d arrays (in that case tensor objects). With `i` and `j` you can define the indices that are used for the matrix multiplication and the `by` argument is your loop variable (`i` in your case).

Comment: Vectorization for speed-up or readability/maintenance?

Comment: For speed up.  The looping is too slow ( i have something like 20,000 instead of 100)

Comment: Then you could also use the packages `Rcpp` and `RcppArmadillo`...

Comment: That is to re-write using C++ though right?

Comment: Is mul.tensor not any faster than a loop?

Comment: Writing RcppArmadillo code must be quite straightforward. It has a syntax akin to matlab.

Comment: `Mul.tensor` should be faster. Yes, `Rcpp` involves C++. It takes some time to pick up but together with `RcppArmadillo` it's really useful if you do a lot of stuff that cannot be vectorized easily.

Comment: Actually, I have just checked `mul.tensor` - does not seem to be faster than a loop. Did not expect that.

Comment: Seemed strange that your reproducible example returns 104. It turned out that regardless of the data generation, `sum(Eprob)` is 1, so, I am little puzzled as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I got rid of some functional form manipulations but they are easy to add back in.  I took out for simplificty.  Do you think I should add back in?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to store `dfmat` as a named matrix, rather than list of matrices?

Comment: Main bottleneck is the name look-up `Xt = dfmat [which(dfmat [,'unit']==i),] `, If you instead store`dfmat` as list of matrices, then access its elements as `Xt = dfmat [[i]]`, it will be several times faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make my remarks in comment column clear, suppose we have `dfmat` as a list of matrices. It is almost always easier to work with a list of matrices than one big named matrix. Also if you want to fully vectorize the solution given here, you might want to obtain a block diagonal matrix using `bdiag` from `Matrix` package which acts on lists.

```
set.seed(1)
dfarray=array(rnorm(5*3*14,0,1),dim=c(3,14,5))
# dfmats as a list of matrices
dfmats <- lapply(1:3, function(i)matrix(rnorm(13*14), nrow=13))
```

Multiplication by `iota` is either `colSums` or `rowSums`, therefore we can simplify the operation as in `f`.

```
f <- function(Xbeta) rowSums(Xbeta / matrix(colSums(Xbeta), nrow=nrow(Xbeta), ncol=ncol(Xbeta), byrow=T)) / ncol(Xbeta)
#profits is written as a function for benchmarking
#cost and p are ignored as they can be easily added back in.
profits <- function(){ 
    Xbetas <- lapply(seq_len(dim(dfarray)[1]), function(i) exp(dfmats[[i]] %*% dfarray[i,,]))
    Eprobs <- lapply(Xbetas, f)
    unlist(Eprobs)
}
```

And your approach

```
profits1 <- function(){
    profit=numeric(0)
    for(i in 1:dim(dfarray)[1]){
        j=13
        beta = dfarray[i,,]
        Xt = dfmat [which(dfmat [,'unit']==i),1:14]    #this takes a set of 13, Xt is 13x14
        
        Xbeta = exp( Xt %*% beta )
        iota = c(rep(1, j))
        denom = iota%*%Xbeta
        deno <- colSums(Xbeta)
        s <- iota%*%denom
        Prob =  (Xbeta/ s)
        Eprob = rowSums(Prob)/dim(dfarray)[3]  #the 100 coming from the last dim of array
        profit = c(profit,Eprob)
        
    }
    return(profit)
}
dfmat <- do.call(rbind, dfmats)
dfmat <- cbind(dfmat,rep(1:3, each=13))
colnames(dfmat)[15]='unit'
```

Check that they give identical results

```
all.equal(profits(), profits1())
[1] TRUE
```

## Benchmark

I ran this on AWS EC2 free-tie instance accessed via http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/.

```
dfarray=array(rnorm(100*10000*14,0,1),dim=c(10000,14,100))
dfmats <- lapply(1:10000, function(i)matrix(rnorm(13*14), nrow=13))
```

From your initial construct, you can transform `dfmat` to list `dfmats` as    `dfmats <- lapply(1:3, function(i)dfmat[which(dfmat [,'unit']==i),1:14])` but this is a very costly conversion. Creating `dfmat` from `dfmats` is reasonably less costly.

```
dfmat <- do.call(rbind, dfmats)
dfmat <- cbind(dfmat,rep(1:10000, each=13))
colnames(dfmat)[15]='unit'
```

Notice an exceptional speed-up using `list`, and perils of dreadful name-lookup cost.

```
system.time(a1 <- profits1())
#   user  system elapsed 
#250.885   4.442 255.394 
system.time(a <- profits())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.717   0.429   3.167 
all.equal(a, a1)
#[1] TRUE
```

PS: I've noticed that you have asked a several questions potentially related to this question, had all answered. I'll be happy if you share how you successfully put those in a good use.